# C++ lambda: good reference vs. bad reference

Tags: c++, lambda, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm watching a CppCon 2015 video: why capturing by value is good while by reference is bad.

[image]

Arthur explained, but I don't get it ... Arthur says a bad reference is referring to a local variable then exit, but after exiting the stack shall clean up and local variables are gone, so what's the problem?

Comment: Do you know what's wrong with `int& f() {int x = 5; return x;}`?

Comment: The problem is exactly what you said -- you're returning something that holds a reference to something that is gone. What can you do with such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to try to explain what @Barry's answer has said in another way.

Let's write down what's happened inside `BAD_increment_by`.

1. There is a local variable, `y`.
2. The lambda capture `y` by reference. This creates a reference called `y`. Well, they happens to have the same name, that's confusing... Let's call the first one "value `y`", and the second one "reference `y`".
3. The body of the lambda uses reference `y`.
4. The lambda is returned by `BAD_increment_by`.

After returning from `BAD_increment_by`,

1. Value `y` no longer exists.
2. Reference `y` is still pointing to value `y`...
3. Wait! value `y` does not exist! Reference `y` is pointing to something doesn't exist!

When someone invoke the lambda,

1. Reference `y` is read.
2. Since reference `y` is a reference, we are redirected to value `y`.
3. Errr... Is it really value `y` or just my hallucination?

The conclusion is: When the lambda is invoked, a dangling reference is used. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I got it.

Answer (score 8):

`BAD_increment_by` returns a closure that contains in it a reference to `y`, but `y` goes out of scope when that function returns, so it contains a dangling reference. Any attempt to call that closure is undefined behavior.

It's bad for the same reason that:

```
int& BAD_copy(int x) { return x; }
```

is bad.

Comment: Do you mean that by writing "[&]", what returned is no longer a *value* of 7, but a *reference* of a local anonymous variable with value 7?

Comment: @athos Not returned. The lambda itself has a member of type `int&` that refers to local variable `y`.

Comment: Then I don't get it. So the BAD_increment_by example has a member of type int&, anonymous so let's just call it ry, that refers to local variable y, but what can go wrong? Nobody is using ry...

Comment: @athos `y` is destroyed at the end of the function call. You have a reference to a dead object. Calling that lambda uses that reference - undefined behavior.

Comment: @athos `y` no longer exists when the call `plus5(2)` is made, which attempts to access `y`

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a lambda as shorthand for a class with `operator()` defined so it can be treated like a function.

```
auto BAD_increment_by(int y)
{
    return [&](int x){return x+y;};
}
```

Can be considered short hand for the following:

```
struct BadClosure
{
    int&   y;
    BadClosure(int& y) // y is the only variable in scope
        : y(y)         // So the `&` only captures 'y'
    {}
    auto operator()(int x){return x+y;}
};
auto BAD_increment_by(int y)
{
    return BadClosure(y);
}
```

So if I use the above:

```
int main()
{
     // This object now has a reference to 
     // parameter 'y' from the function `BAD_increment_by()`
     //
     // But this function has exited.
     // So the reference held by this object is no longer
     // valid (ie it is a dangling reference).
     auto addTwo = BAD_increment_by(2);


     // Now use it
     // Internally this access the member y
     // which is a reference to the parameter 'y'
     // from a function that is no longer executing.
     std::cout << addTwo(5) << "\n";
}
```